# Xamarin Prism application exiting right after launch on Android without throwing exception

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

I am developing a Xamarin application and I have just started using the prism framework.

I have a very basic application consisting of a main page. It works fine on UWP, but when I try to run it on my Android phone, the application starts, and then exit right away, without throwing any exception or logging any error.

I tried to put a breakpoint in the OnCreate method (which I haven't touched):

```
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            LoadApplication(new App(new AndroidInitializer()));
        }
```

And the breakpoint (on the first line of the method) is never hit.

I haven't modified the code of the Android application, so I'm pretty confused right now, any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried putting a try ... catch in your OnCreate method?

Comment: Yes I just did try doing a try...catch in the Oncreate method, and no exception was caught. In the output I do have the following message when launching the app in debug mode: "This debug engine does not support exception conditions. The condition(s) will be ignored."

Comment: Can you step through the constructor? Is there any other code being called before OnCreate() ?

Comment: This might help you : https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/95242/vs-15-2-update-not-hitting-any-breakpoints - recommendation is to downgrade Xamarin to 4.4.0.34

Comment: Thank you for the link, this doesn't seem to be the problem I am facing though, since I am able to debug properly and hit breakpoints on other platforms. OnCreate is the first method that is called that I have access to, so an error seems to occur before that step.